# Load data with controller inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, webpack-encore

In symfony 4.4 application with Webpack Encore, I have an input field in a twig template. This template load a javascript asset which need to call a function which fetch data matching with the current value of the input field.

Input inside my template templates/mypage.html.twig

```
<input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" id="searchInput">
```

My javascript file assets/js/search.js

```
const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');

searchInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
    //here I need a function to fetch data matching with searchInput.value
}
```

I have here a method inside my controller which return the search result for a given value src/SearchController.php

```
public function search($value) {
    $searchResult = $this->myRepository->findAllMatching($value);
    // here I need to return the result of search
}
```

How can I run the search whenever the value of the input changes ?

Comment: What about writing some code that triggers an AJAX request on changing the value of that specific input field?

Comment: Thank you Nico Haase, yes that is possible, I am just looking for a solution without Ajax, if it exists.

Comment: You want to load dynamic data from the server, based on the input, in real-time, but without AJAX? Why? That's exactly what AJAX was introduced for

Comment: I'm just looking if we can do it somehow with Symfony or some bundle. So I will resolve it with Ajax.

Comment: Of course you can do that with Symfony or some bundle - most probably, that will also use AJAX